# Celery autoscale task received before scaling

Tags: celery, celery-task

I tried use with celery this command

```
celery -A test worker --autoscale=10,0 --pool=eventlet --loglevel=info
```

but with autoscale my program is not working. The issue is that the task is received before scaling is processed. If I use command with defined number of concurrency

```
 celery -A test worker -c 10 --pool=eventlet --loglevel=info
```

my program works well. I am using celery version 5.2.1.

```
[2023-08-05 23:47:03,635: INFO/MainProcess] Task test.save_video[e994faf6-3426-49c8-b665-5c53db45b67e] received
[2023-08-05 23:47:03,888: INFO/MainProcess] Scaling up 1 processes.
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Is this not getting executed? Celery has concept of master and child processes when using with prefork mode. It's could be same with eventlet too. Master receives the tasks from broker and distributes them over child eventlets, where they are actually executed.